# Regex Matching - Python

Tags: python

I need to write a regex matching pattern code to either return true if there is one '+' between two words and nothing else. I have written the code to check if there is only one '+' in the string but how will I check it is between two words?
The code is below:

```
import re

inputStr= "ali+ahmedafaw+"
inputStr2= "hello+world+again"

plus=re.findall(r'[+]', inputStr)

print (plus)

l_plus=len(plus)
print "The length is ",l_plus

if l_plus<=1:
    print "True"
else:
    print "False"
```

Comment: Something like `w+\+\w+`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reference - What does this regex mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean)

Comment: it's "regex" as in "regular expression" not "redex"

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on what you mean by *word*. If you mean a word with more than one character, you can simply use `[a-zA-Z]+` around the `+` character. Or other patterns which will match different characters like `\w` to match word characters.

```
re.search(r'[a-zA-Z]+\+[a-zA-Z]+', input_str)
```

But if you just want it doesn't appears at the leading and trailing of your text you can use negative look-around:

```
re.search(r'(?<!^)\+(?!$)', input_str)
```